# Cannot import the following key file: tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx when running building tSLQt

Tags: tsqlt

I am trying to run `tSQLt` solution locally by following instructions in the `tSQLt\Build\Install the tSQLt build.docx`.

Re-built `tSQLtCLR` solution:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: tSQLtCLR, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: tSQLtTestUtilCLR, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: tSQLtExternalAccessKey, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: UnsignedEmpty, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  tSQLtCLR -> E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\bin\Debug\tSQLtCLR.dll
2>  tSQLtTestUtilCLR -> E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtTestUtilCLR\bin\Debug\tSQLtTestUtilCLR.dll
3>  tSQLtExternalAccessKey -> E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtExternalAccessKey\bin\Debug\tSQLtExternalAccessKey.dll
4>  UnsignedEmpty -> E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\UnsignedEmpty\bin\Debug\UnsignedEmpty.dll
========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've create self-signed certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Then I've created pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\OfficialSigningKey\tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem
```

Then I double clicked on that new pfx file and imported it for current user.

Finally run `Menu / Tools / tSQLt local Dev_tSQL` and getting following error:

```
+-------------------+
: Starting BUILD    :
+-------------------+
NAnt 0.92 (Build 0.92.4543.0; release; 2012-06-09)
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///E:/Source/tSQLt/Build/tSQLt.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
Target(s) specified: all 


init:


init.tSQLt:

   [delete] Deleting directory 'E:\Source\tSQLt\Build\temp'.
    [mkdir] Creating directory 'E:\Source\tSQLt\Build\temp'.

clr.compile:

     [echo] Compile CLR Command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" tSQLtCLR.csproj /p:Configuration=CruiseControl /nologo
     [exec] Build started 2019-08-11 10:47:46 AM.
     [exec] Project "E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
     [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_C20B79DE0583A5C1 [E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj]
     [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx" was canceled. [E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj]
     [exec] Done Building Project "E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Build FAILED.
     [exec] 
     [exec] "E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
     [exec] (ResolveKeySource target) -> 
     [exec]   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_C20B79DE0583A5C1 [E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj]
     [exec]   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx" was canceled. [E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj]
     [exec] 
     [exec]     0 Warning(s)
     [exec]     2 Error(s)
     [exec] 
     [exec] Time Elapsed 00:00:00.49

BUILD FAILED

E:\Source\tSQLt\Build\tSQLt.build(53,4):
External Program Failed: cmd (return code was 1)

Total time: 0.8 seconds.

+-------------------+
: BUILD FAILED      :
+-------------------+
```

UPDATE:

After pfx file was generated and 4 of them were replaced in the project. After that I open `tSQLtCLR` solution and went to each project properties (except UnsignedEmpty project), then to the `Signing` tab and there I tick `Sign the assembly" tick, choose the key. It asked for password I didn't entered any, just clicked OK as the key was created without password. Then I clean/rebuild the solution and got the errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3214,5): error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_FAD69C25E7450957
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3214,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx" was canceled.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3214,5): error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_3A487AA7CCDAEF2F
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3214,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx" was canceled.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3214,5): error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file: tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_5C6CEC0DAE821947
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3214,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx" was canceled.
4>  UnsignedEmpty -> E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\UnsignedEmpty\bin\Debug\UnsignedEmpty.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is indeed password protected. You need to overwrite it with your own key locally.

Make sure you mark the file as exception in Git should you plan to do a pull request in the future.

Comment: I generated pfx file out of my local cert/key. What's next? Do I need to replace  tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\OfficialSigningKey\tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx file with that? Any password configuration?

Comment: Yes, replace that file. No password configuration needed.

Comment: I've updated the question. Could you please take a look? I'm still getting that error.

Comment: Can you open the CLR solution in VS and build it there once?  If it builds in VS, then it should work in the script afterwards, too. If it doesn’t build, it should give as more info as to why.

Comment: I've rebuilt the project and it still gives the same error.

Comment: When you created the new key, did you set a password? If so, try to recreate it without.

Comment: Re-created the key without password (passkey was entered only). Replaced tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx file in 4 locations (tSQLtCKR, OfficialSigningKey, tSQLtExternalAccessKey, tSQLtTestUtilCLR). Also imported it to windows, by doubleclicking on it it (then next, next...). Still getting the same error.

Comment: In Visual Studio, modify the project to not include the key. Then build it. Then add your key back in. Then build it again. If that doesn't help, go through those steps again, but use VS to create the key for you.

Comment: what does it mean "use VS to create the key for you"? I've cloned the project to another directory, followed the steps from the instructions (basically  needed just run Setup.bat file). Then open tSQtLCLR project and clean/re-build the solution. Did I need to do something else as this didn't help :(

Comment: could you please help? I almost finished main development part for faking of external synonyms so I want to add tests and try how is it going...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-assembly-and-manifest-signing?view=vs-2019

Comment: Just as a side note, tSQLt is developed using TDD. To have your addition accepted, the tests need to cover your codebase equally well. Also think about all edge cases, like synonyms to procedures in another database that use a tabletype parameter.

Comment: I support only views and tables currently

Comment: I updated the question, after signing the projects the solution doesn't build.

Comment: Now, I did recommend you use VS to generate a new key. Doesn’t look like you did that.

Comment: finally! thanks! it's failing now but because of another reason.