# Running tSQLt project from sources fails on the due to the Public Token mismatch

Tags: sql-server, pfx, tsqlt, snk

I'm trying to do [some improvements](https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/pull/48) for tSQLt framework and I'm mostly finish, but can't do that as few tests related to the certificate I wasn't touching are still failing:

```
 [exec] |18|[InstallExternalAccessKeyTests].[test creates correct certificate in master]                                                       |    120|Failure|
 [exec] |19|[InstallExternalAccessKeyTests].[test tSQLt can be set to EXTERNAL ACCESS after InstallExternalAccessKey executed]                 |    333|Failure|
 [exec] |20|[InstallExternalAccessKeyTests].[test tSQLtExternalAccessKey install data is signed with same key as tSQLt.clr]                    |     10|Failure|
```

The failing error is:

```
Expected: %publickeytoken=8c9a92de0f9c7794,%
Actual: tsqltclr, version=1.0.7216.13228, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=8d3f4bf59e4c22fd, processorarchitecture=msil
```

I'll try to describe my installation process.

I installed this framework sources by using [following guideline](https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/blob/master/Build/Install%20the%20tSQLt%20build.docx). However I couldn't start the project after that as it was failing with the following errors and the whole problem solving was done in that [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440769/cannot-import-the-following-key-file-tsqltofficialsigningkey-pfx-when-running-b):

> [exec]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5):
>   error MSB3325: Cannot import the following key file:
>   tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected.
>   To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually
>   install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key
>   container name: VS_KEY_C20B79DE0583A5C1
>   [E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj] [exec]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5):
>   error MSB3321: Importing key file "tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx" was
>   canceled. [E:\Source\tSQLt\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR\tSQLtCLR.csproj]

to pass this issue, I've created new keys for every project with no password:

[image]

I see that it created `snk` file, not as original `pfx`. After that I've tried to run the build again and it failed with the errors I mentioned above.

Comment: Why using `tsql` framework  at all? It includes so many code in your database code, a lot of SQL CLR function. I have try to use if for 2 big projects over the year and it fails badly. It will be better to create own test using .net or/and SQL and execute them via some tool to get parallel execution.

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly are you talking about. There are only several SQL CLR functions there. Additionally it is very stable and "fails badly" just sounds strange. Even Redgate included this framework to their products. You can google for it and you'll find that it is the best unit testing framework so far.

Comment: I know it is the best, but it is not good. I have used it a lot of times and attend a few online demonstrations, requested enhancement and stuff, but I end up creating own tests. That's my advice - do not rely on this framework.

Comment: I use it for many years already and it always worked well for me, on the big projects also.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1152/7/error-cannot-import-the-following-key-file-mykeypfx-the-key-file-may-be-password-protected-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2008---2015)

The following error may occur when building projects for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - 2015.

*Error*: **Cannot import the following key file: mykey.pfx. The key file may be password protected.**

> Cannot import the following key file: mykey.pfx. The key file may be
> password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate
> again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with
> the following key container name: VS_KEY_C1D3ACB8FBF1AGK4

**SOLUTION 1:**

Click Start > All Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio >Visual Studio
Tools > Visual Studio Command Prompt. Type the following command

```
sn -i "c:\Pathtofile\.pfx" VS_KEY_C1D3ACB8FBF1AGK4
```

**Note**: The sn.exe with the -i parameter, installs a key pair from into a key container named.**Re-import** the PFX file into Visual Studio.

**SOLUTION 2:**

- Open Project Properties.
- Click on the Signing section.
- Where it says ‘Choose a strong name key file:’, re-select the current value from the drop-down box
- Visual Studio will now prompt you for the password. Enter it. You might get another error message:
  ”An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist” > You can simply ignore this message.
- Click the ‘Change Password” button
- Enter the original password in all three boxes and click OK. If you’d like to change
- your password (or if your old password doesn’t meet complexity requirements), you can do so now.
- Repeat for each key file in your project.
  Save your project and do a rebuild.

**SOLUTION 3:**

Get a copy of openssl for windows at slproweb.com or use a Linux box as they all pretty much have it.
Run the following to export to a key file

> openssl pkcs12 -in certfile.pfx -out backupcertfile.key
>
> openssl pkcs12 -export -out certfiletosignwith.pfx -keysig -in backupcertfile.key

Then in the project properties you can use the PFX file

**SOLUTION 4:**

The final solution for this issue is to give up on Visual Studio for signing purpose and use **Signtool** instead.

**Updated Answer**

It seems that your TFS Build Service account has no required permission to access the signingKey.pfx on build agent machine.
Make sure you have this file on build agent machine first.

Then follow below steps:

1. Log on the build agent as **your local build service account** (Better have Administrator permission)
2. Open a visual studio command prompt and **navigate to the directory
   the key is stored in**
3. Type command `sn –i signingKey.pfx VS_KEY_EFCA4C5B6DFD4B4F`(Ensure that you use the key name appearing in the error message)
4. When prompted for a password type the password for the pfx file
5. Then rebuild it

**Note:** If you are not running Visual Studio as an Administrator try doing that as well.

More details you can reference the answer from  *Brandon Manchester* [Cannot import the keyfile 'blah.pfx' - error 'The keyfile may be password protected'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815366/cannot-import-the-keyfile-blah-pfx-error-the-keyfile-may-be-password-protec)

Comment: I do not know password for a key

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev You can simply open `Project` -> `Property` ->  `Signing` and uncheck the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" checkbox.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Updated answer too. check that as well

Comment: All provided solutions in your case required password. I do not have one. `Sign the ClickOnce manifests` is unchecked and DISABLED. I'm trying to do everything locally, so there is no permissions issues (I've tried to run this command line under the administrator)

Comment: Kumar, any other ideas?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev which version you are using?

Comment: If you are talking about Visual Studio, then it is 2017

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev http://www.slickit.ca/2010/09/fix-cannot-import-following-key-file.html Can you try this

Comment: There 7 point that says "Enter the original password in all three boxes and click OK. If you’d like to change your password (or if your old password doesn’t meet complexity requirements), you can do so now. ". As I stated already, that I do not have password.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev you must enable `Sign the ClickOnce manifests` let me see why it was disabled

Comment: It is greyed out, I can't select it. Maybe DB projects do not support that..

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev just right click on the pfx file from VS Solution Explorer and select “Open Command Prompt”. A prompt opens right at the folder containing the key file, and I enter the command: `n -i magellanicKey.pfx tSQLtOfficialSigningKey`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201875/discussion-between-dmitrij-kultasev-and-vignesh-kumar-a).

Comment: I've answered in chat, that I do not have such option

Comment: refer this, you must have https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/strongly-named-assemblies-installing-a-pfx-to-your-machine/

Comment: in that example author knows the password and I don't

Comment: You can enter password for that section

Comment: Failed to parse the PKCS#12 blob in tSQLtOfficialSigningKey.pfx -- The specified network password is not correct.